# curly brace and square brackets in set() in python

Tags: python, set, brackets

I don't get why current.value is surrounded by square brackets here:

```
    current = linkedlist.head
    seen = set([current.value])
```

my first instinct was to write
'''
    seen = set(current.value)
'''

And I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: "my first instinct was to write ''' seen = set(current.value) '''"—try that and see what happens. Then maybe the `[]` will become clear.

Comment: The set constructor require an *iterable* of items to initialize the set with. Alternatively, you can use a set literal the following way: `seen = {current.value}`

Comment: @Chris I tried that, current.value is int number. I don't get why putting it in "[]" makes it an iterable.

Comment: @user3141805, `[1]` is a list with a single element. Lists are iterable.